# How to kill KDE screensaver from command line

Tags: screensaver, kde4

Sometimes lock-screen just can't be unlocked in KDE, so I have to kill it from TTY.

Update: in 4.13 `plasma-overlay` always respawns. Any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, in KDE 4.13.3 (as shipped with Kubuntu 14.04 LTS), I cannot enter anything into the password field of the locker, nor can I press any buttons with my mouse. I use the following workarounds for this issue:

- triggering suspend-to-RAM by closing my laptop's lid (not sure if this the default configuration, maybe you have to set it up first) and then resuming
- if the above does not work, I switch to a "real" console with e.g. Ctrl-Alt-F1 (this by itself has to work, of course) and kill the locker process with `killall kscreenlocker_greet`

The actions mentioned above will not disable the locker but they at least make the input work again.

One might also want to have a look at [this KDE bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=314663) for possibly better workarounds (did not have time to evaluate them yet).

Answer (score 0):

#### KDE 4.10.5 - 4.12

Try killing `plasma-overlay` process, this should help.

Comment: Or you can stop and start the K Display Manager (KDM).

Comment: Yes, but this way all unsaved data in opened X applications will be lost.

Comment: Correct. I didn't know that you don't want to lose the unsaved data.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore with `4.13`